# If a passenger damages another passenger's property (accidentally) on a flight, who is responsible?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, security, passenger-rights

This came up after listening to a Rick Steves podcast on travel.

He and I have both apparently wondered - when the passenger in front suddenly reclines their seat and nearly decapitates your laptop - if they do damage it when doing so, legally, is it:

- the airline's responsibility
- your responsibility
- the passenger's responsibility
- that passenger asking for the fourth gin and tonic's responsibility
- nobody's legal responsibility, and tough luck
- the pilot's?

In so much as - you'll need to get it fixed/replaced, so who is going to be paying for it?

I'd like an official law/statement/precedent on this, ideally.

Comment: I guess my point was - do you have any recourse? On the ground if someone accidentally crashes into your car, they pay by law, not if they volunteer to do so.  I'm expecting this would apply in-flight too.

Comment: Only in a lawsuit-happy country like the US would this even be a concern. Its like saying that the drink spilled on your clothes due to turbulence and now its the airline's fault.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid am not in the US, but if someone accidentally smashed my laptop, I'd be pretty upset.

Comment: Can a seat really decapitate a laptop (they don't move by a lot)? Shouldn't you setup your laptop in a way that take into account seat reclining (which is an action that have a high chance of hapenning)? Negligence might be more on the laptop owner than the person sitting in front. (Tort?)

Comment: My problem with this question is at the_lotus states... how could a laptop (or really anything) be damaged while set on a foldout tray table? Is it possible to open the lid (of the laptop) and jam it under the inset of the table in such a way that when the seat reclines, the inset drops more than the table itself? I'm not trying to be argumentative, just wondering.

Comment: I don't think reclining will break a laptop, but some guy banged my laptop when I had it stored in the overhead compartment. I had to take the damages myself. It's just like someone spills coffee on your laptop. Starbucks wouldn't fix it.

Comment: Generally, anyone who reclines a seat (in economy) on an airliner, is basically a bad person. It is unbelievably un-social and rude to recline your seat.

Comment: Related question on Aviation.SE: [Which country is responsible for prosecution if a crime is committed over international waters?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/which-country-is-responsible-for-prosecution-if-a-crime-is-committed-over-intern)

Comment: @CGCampbell: I have had this happening on some trains, where tables would fold into the inset at the seat, but were mounted in a way to not change in orientation or height above the floor when the seat in front of yours is reclined (along with the inset). See, for example, [this photo](http://www.berliner.de/sites/default/files/artikel/bilder/abteilp1250848.jpg), and note how the table is mounted to the fixed seat base, not to the reclineable backrest. In general, such train seats are designed very similarly to plane seats, so the same may be the case on some planes.

Comment: and that people, is why we carry travel insurance...

Comment: @jwenting aha, but who's travel insurance should cover it - yours, or that of the passenger who reclines? ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo I'd leave that for the insurance companies to figure out (if you even get the name and insurance of the other party, which I doubt you'd get from most people).

Comment: [Related](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/95422).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In most juristictions that operate with something approaching sanity, someone is liable for accidental damage in the following three cases:

1. They caused the damage deliberately or with "blameworthy carelessness".
2. They have entered into a contract where they explicitly accept to be responsible for the risk.
3. The law contains an explicit exception for the situation and says they are liable in the situation even without wrongdoing or contract ("strict liability"). For example, in most places the owner of an aircraft is liable for any damage it causes even if the owner did nothing wrong and the one who suffered the damage is not a passenger.

In the present question it seems that the only thing that could possibly apply is whether the passenger who reclined his seat would be liable under theory (1). It seems to be easy enough to argue that he was being careless, but what a court will have to decide is then whether this carelessness was "blameworthy" (my word, but different jurisdictions use various legal codewords for essentially this concept) -- in other words, was or wasn't he *less* careful that one could reasonably expect people in general to be?

I suspect that most courts would come to the conclusion that no, one cannot in general expect passengers not to recline their seats when the airline provides a seat that can recline -- and no, one cannot in general expect passengers to always ask they guy behind them before they recline, however nice it would be if everyone did that. So it will rule that the guy was not "blameworthily" careless, and can't be liable.

You could certainly have your day in court trying to convince it otherwise, though, if you find a court with jurisdiction over the passenger.

Comment: At least in the UK law, "criminal damage" offence includes "reckless" acts, i.e. acts where a the person could have foreseen that damage was likely to be caused by the actions yet proceeded with the actions nonetheless.  It's this matter of "recklessness" that's usually the sticking point in courts.  If you can prove that the person in front of you could have reasonably foreseen that suddenly reclining the seat would cause the damage, then, at least under the UK law, he/she is liable.

Comment: @pnuts "blameworthy carelessness" explicitly means *some* cases of accidental damage, depending on the circumstances - it all comes down to a (subjective?) evaluation of the circumstances, is the behavior "blameworthy" or not. E.g. if I accidentally stumble on a fragile item in a shop and break it, it's definitely an accident and most likely 'blameworthy carelessness' where I'd be expected to pay for it.

Comment: @pnuts depends on the cost of the laptop - small claims court (or the equivalent depending on the country) is definitely an option, it's simply a question if the required effort * chance of success is worth it.

Comment: @pnuts I agree - the major issue here may be not the jurisdiction details of the aircraft, but the jurisdiction/nationality of the other passenger; if you come from the same country (which is quite possible) then it's plausible, if it's a french plane flying from Egypt to Sudan, and one of you is from USA and the other from China... then forget about it unless the harm is so huge that you can get the local police involved.

Comment: Could the passenger in front not claim an expectation that seats recline at an acceptable velocity and that seats capable of reclining suddenly enough to damage something belonging to the person behind indicate fault on the part of the airline?

Comment: @AleksG As a tall individual, reclining seats have large ramifications on my comfort. Worse, a seat on a flight caused bruising to my knees. Changing the another passengers space will always have the potential for damage.

Comment: @hippietrail the passenger can and likely will make such a claim, that's why a court decision would be needed to determine the [lack of] blame depending on all the circumstances.

Comment: @pnuts Yes. I never recline on the principle that it is terrible, regardless of the space I have. I avoid the inevitable discomfort by preloading with booze and sleeping.

Comment: I'd imagine the court would consider that the person with the laptop could have reasonably anticipated that he seat would recline too. The blame is probably too spread out for anyone to be held liable, so it would go down as accidental damage and an insurance claim.

Comment: @AleksG That can't possibly be a correct statement of the law. If I drive across town, it's reasonably foreseeable that I might cause someone who otherwise would have made a light to get stuck at the light where they might get shot. Surely I'm not liable for that just because it wouldn't have happened had I not been on the road and the sequence of events are foreseeable. Recklessness typically has an element of not using ordinary or appropriate care. IMO, if anyone is reckless here, it's the person who places their laptop such that reclining will damage it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Have a look here: http://www.cps.gov.uk/legal/a_to_c/criminal_damage/ - this is the government guidelines to the prosecution.  It states: _Recklessness" for the purposes of the Criminal Damage Act is now defined as follows:

"A person acts recklessly within the meaning of section 1 of the Criminal Damage Act 1971 with respect to:

A circumstance when he is aware of a risk that it exists or will exist;
A result when he/she is aware of a risk that it will occur; and
It is, in the circumstances known to him, unreasonable to take the risk."_

Comment: @AleksG And there you go, you have the additional element of it being "unreasonable to take the risk". So your original statement was incorrect for just the reason I said it was. It is not sufficient that the harm be reasonably foreseeable, it must also be unreasonable to take the risk.

Answer (score 4):

From a common sense point of view - #5 .... its an accident, deal with it.

In the hands of a lawyer - #1, #3 & #6 .... the shotgun approach, sue them all and hope one settles rather than fight the case in court.

Comment: "the shotgun approach". I should use that phrase more often.

Comment: "I placed an expensive, fragile item on a shakey surface behind a heavy object that could move backwards quickly without warning at almost any time. This resulted in the item being broken. Who can I sue?"

Answer (score 2):

As for liability, everything depends on what jurisdiction you'll be able to work. If it will be the European (continental - based on Napoleonic Code) law, then you're liable for every damage **you** have caused, and the factor of 'recklessness' or 'guilt' is unimportant.

So the question will arise, who have caused the damage to the laptop, which is not obvious.

If you place your laptop on the middle of the street, and someones drive on it, you will be the one that have damaged it - by placing it on the middle of the street - not the driver. So if you place your laptop in unadequate place, and therefore the damage, you can expect the court will find you responsible for the damage.

But if you have placed your laptop on the desk, and the passanger before you have reclined rapidly without looking back, they will be most likely responsible for the damage - the same as if they throw it out of your hand by rapid movement.

However, if you can prove, that the seats are so designed, that such damages are too likely to happen, the airline may be made responsible - it all depends on what the judge will find 'too likely' or 'badly designed'. If the seat decline when pressing a button which is easy to press accidentally, it's very likely the responsibility of the airline.

It would be hard to find suitable precedent, because each of such cases will be handled individually.

Comment: I don't think that is a correct summary of "European continental" law in general. For example, in German law the default rule of liability (§276 _Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch_) is that people are liable for "Vorsatz und Fahrlässigkeit", more or less: deliberate or negligent. Merely being the "cause" of damage without negligence would not trigger liability under this rule.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a domestic flight, then the laws of the country take precedence (i.e., everyone else's guesswork answers probably apply.)

If this is an international flight, however, the Warsaw Convention covers this. According to Clauses 17 and 18 of the Warsaw Convention, **the airline is liable** for **any injury** (to people, clause 17) or **damage** (to property, clause 18) that occurs during the flight.

Comment: Check out article 20: *The carrier is not liable if he proves that he and his agents have taken all necessary measures to avoid the damage or that it was impossible for him or them to take such measures.* So if I smash your laptop (or your face), you won't be able to sue the airline for this.

Comment: Interesting thought, but if the airline seat can recline and destroy a laptop, do you think the seats were designed not to damage laptops? The question isn't about travelers attacking each other - rather just using the equipment installed in the cabin.